# How to deduce const and non-const type without duplicating functions?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-argument-deduction

Let's say I have this function: (which pretty much runs a function on each value in container, and then returns a vector of the result of each iteration)

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

template<class F, class V>
auto vmap(const F &f, const V &v) -> vector<decltype(f(v[0]))> {
    vector<decltype(f(v[0]))> result;
    result.reserve(v.size());
    for (auto &p : v)
        result.push_back(f(p));
    return result;
}
```

I can't call it like this:

```
vector<int> vint = {1,2,3,4,5};
vmap([](auto &p) {return p++;},vint);
```

Because the parametered `vector` is `const`, to make it happen I will have to create two `vmap` that get non-`const` `V` and one that is `const`.

It starts to feel too much when there are multiple containers/`vector`s passed to a function, because it makes me write `2^containers_count` functions.

Is there any(-dirty but working) solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an forwarding reference to bind to both normal l-value references (e.g. `std::vector<int>&`) and r-value references (`std::vector<int>&&`).

The downside is that you're never able to pass by value (only ref, const ref, or r-value ref), though I don't think that'll be a problem for you:

```
template<class F, class V>
auto vmap(F&& f, V&& v) {
    vector<decltype(f(v[0]))> result;
    result.reserve(v.size());
    for (auto& p : v)
        result.push_back(f(p));
    return result;
}
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sWDBfMAvq3sauN9C)

Note that the lambda you pass must be applicable to both const if you're going to pass a const container (Thanks, Miles), so `p++` is out of the question (Although beware that one template instantiation modifies the input and the other doesn't, which may be unexpected):

```
vector<int> vint = {1,2,3,4,5};
vmap([](auto &p) {return p++;},vint);
const std::vector<int> vint2 = vint;
vmap([](auto &p) {return p+1;},vint2);
```

Comment: Re your note: The functor only needs to be applicable to `const` if you pass a `const` container.  [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/858852c55432fb6c)

Comment: That's pretty close, but when I pass `lvalue` it doesn't say it's a read-only object.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @AndyG `vmap([](auto &p){return p++;},vector<int>())`, the compiler doesn't *shout* at me when I do this. (As you said, I need to pass reference)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Why should it? passing `vector<int>()` in the constructor creates an r-value, for which you can construct an r-value reference (`std::vector<int>&&`) in the function.

Comment: @AndyG you proved my question being incomplete, I won't edit it. thanks.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: If you want to prevent temporaries, you can remove one of the ampersands on the `V` template: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Vfk47zz1xBsqkHUY (note that you'll also prevent the ability to std::move an object into your function)

Comment: @AndyG I want to prevent modifications to temporaries, not prevent passing them.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Then there was nothing wrong with your original function. A non-const vector can become const for the purpose of a function call (but not vice-versa). The only problem you had was that the lambda you passed in was attempting to modify the argument (received by const-reference). Fix the lambda, fix your code.

Comment: @AndyG That's what I wanted to allow without losing the ability to pass const containers (removing the const will disallow me passing const, but allow to modify the containers.)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Then you can make a copy as you iterate within the function: ` for (auto p : v)`

Comment: @AndyG but I need the modifications to be done on the original container. C++ is a tricky language.

Comment: @AndyG I want to note that this code is not a logic implementation, but API to solve logical problems. So it needs to expose as much as less hacks, and more features. So trying to fix a problem from the usage of the API is unwanted.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: I don't understand. You want to pass a container as const, but also perform modifications on it within the function? This sounds like a contradiction. I suppose you could capture the vector within your lambda and perform your logic via that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow your functions to modify the vector, than remove the `const` from your function's parameters. The constness of `v` will be deduced from the argument that is given to it.

You also do not need to specify the return type, it will be deduced from the `return` statement.

```
template<class F, class V>
auto vmap(const F &f, V &v) {
    vector<decltype(f(v[0]))> result;
    result.reserve(v.size());
    for (auto&p : v)
        result.push_back(f(p));
    return result;
}
```

Note that `result.reserve(v.size());` will only work for `std::vector`. If you want to generalize your algorithm you will need to remove that line, or specialize for it.

Comment: *You also do not need to specify the return type, it will be deduced from the return statement.* Only in c++14, c++11 doesn't.

Comment: I got: `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<int>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector<int>’`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41683306/7359094) by AndyG as it's more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a lambda that takes a constant vector.
For your example:

```
vmap([](const auto &p) {return p+1;}, vint);
```

Or modify `vmap`, that it does not require a constant vector.
For your example:

```
auto vmap(const F &f, V &v)
```